# Alternate package explorer view

Tags: eclipse

I was experimenting with my eclipse setup trying to find a better way to browse through my projects packages and classes and I found the perfect view...then lost it.

I've tried every view but I can't get it back.  It was like package explorer but it appeared above the code editor and it contained separate views for projects, packages, and classes.  You could click on the leftmost box containing the project, then the middle box would populate with the packages within, then you could click on the package and the right most box would populate with the classes within.

My best guess is it's a way to customize the project explorer or package explorer but I can't seem to figure it out.

I want to say when I found it I was experimenting with working sets but I could be wrong.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Sounds like the Java Browsing *Perspective*.

Comment: That's exactly what it was!  I tried switching to that perspective to see if that was it but I guess I had modified the view so it wasn't displaying the windows.  After closing the perspective and reopening it viola!  Thank you it was driving me crazy!